# I get several "broken file" errors when creating my boot stick

Tags: dual-boot, iso, usb-creator

While creating my boot stick I get 199 separate errors during the ISO extracting process that all say `data error in (insert file name here) file is broken` then it sticks on 99% of the ISO extraction and only offers me an option to close the installer.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: May be something went wrong while downloading the ISO file. Try downloading the ISO again.

Comment: @andrew You have never say what OS is the `.ISO` file and what OS and software are you using. Please, if you create a question, add all the information that you can.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?

   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

   Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
2. If using a CD/DVD, did you burn the disc as slowly as possible?

   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
3. Did you select the media check before trying to install?

   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
4. Did you ever do a "memory check" (another live-media menu choice) on your PC?

   Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media.

Answer (score 0):

Something could have gone wrong while downloading the ISO file. If the suggestions mentioned in the answer above, you need to download the ISO file again. This time download it from Firefox and make sure that there are no interruptions during the download.